# Printer driver for Epson XP6100

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I'm not having any luck trying to find a printer driver for an Epson XP6100. I am running Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

You can find it at [Epson Driver Download Site](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX)

Type `XP-6100` and you'll get the driver.

Comment: Been there no results

Comment: I tested it right now. You probably entered `XP6100`, not `XP-6100`.

Comment: Exactly what happened. Thanks

Comment: Ok I tried all of those drivers and none will install. It says I have to install lsb first and I did.

Comment: Run `sudo apt install -f` and `lsb` will be installed.

Comment: lsb installed still no worky

Comment: Try to reboot. It should work. And also remove and add the printer again. It is hard to tell without any information.